# Visual Studio Code: different color themes for different projects

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have 2 Visual Studio Code instances with two different projects.

Is there a way to make VS Code instances' themes different from each other depending on the project?

Answer (score 49):

> // Specifies the color theme used in the workbench.

```
"workbench.colorTheme": "...……….",
```

If you put that into your "`WORKSPACE SETTINGS`" and **not** "`USER SETTINGS`" then you will get different themes for each workspace.  When you open your setting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd>  (that's a comma), then above the right-hand editor you will see "USER SETTINGS" and "WORKSPACE SETTINGS", chose the workspace settings and then click on the pencil icon to the left of the `workbench.colortheme` setting to change it.

---

If you don't want to change your whole theme just to quickly differentiate workspaces, try some combo of these settings in your WORKSPACE SETTINGS:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

  "activityBar.background": "#f00", 
  "titleBar.activeBackground": "#f00",
  "statusBar.background": "#f00"
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to have a different theme for each project in the workspace? Or at least change the file association so I can differentiate between frontend and backend when both are in JavaScript?

Comment: I don't understand why this has to be done in a workspace file. Why can't it work in a project settings file? I thought the point of a workspace file was to track it with git and share it with everyone that works on the same project. So wouldn't it make more sense for something like a color theme to be in a file that won't be tracked by git so that each developer can choose a different custom color them for each project?

Answer (score 38):

You can use a great VS Code extension called [Peacock](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.vscode-peacock) developed by John Papa.

Comment: I like this -- I wasn't looking to change my whole color theme ... just get enough of a certain color I associate with a given environment in my face that it'd be harder to forget which one I was looking at.  This does the trick.

Comment: Please check out the other extensions developed by John Papa, you might like them as well. They are super useful for Angular devs!!

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me. in each project folder create a .vscode subfolder if it doesn't already exist. In each folder create a separate settings.json file.  in this file paste in the following:

for example my front end gives me a yellow title bar:

```
{
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "non-relative",
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "titleBar.activeForeground": "#000",
    "titleBar.inactiveForeground": "#000000CC",
    "titleBar.activeBackground": "#ffc600",
    "titleBar.inactiveBackground": "#ffc600CC"
  },
  "appService.zipIgnorePattern": [
    "node_modules{,/**}",
    ".vscode{,/**}"
  ]
}
```

for backend i use this which gives me a red title bar:

```
{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "titleBar.activeForeground": "#000",
    "titleBar.inactiveForeground": "#000000CC",
    "titleBar.activeBackground": "#eb2568",
    "titleBar.inactiveBackground": "#eb2568CC"
  },
  "appService.zipIgnorePattern": [
    "node_modules{,/**}",
    ".vscode{,/**}"
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: This only works if you open each project independently it seems but not for containered projects or remotes. Open for comments and please prove me wrong, I would like to have that for container projects, too.