# Different theme per window in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to open 2 Visual Studio Code sessions with different themes? Maybe like this:

- Window 1: light theme → live system
- Window 2: dark theme → development system

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code: different color themes for different projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571748/visual-studio-code-different-color-themes-for-different-projects)

Comment: related feature-request issue ticket, which suggests the user to find an extension that does it: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/44268

Comment: The question is ambiguous. The answers are about different themes for different workspaces etc. What I want to ask: can I have different themes for different *windows*, so that the theme in a window is readable on the monitor I'm looking at (e.g. with an auxiliary e-ink monitor).

Answer (score 418):

You can have a different theme per workspace/folder by adjusting the `workbench.colorTheme` in the workspace settings.

1. Open a new VSCode window.
2. Open the project folder where you would like to have a different color theme.
3. Navigate to File > Preferences > Settings.
4. Select the "Workspace Settings" tab at the top of the settings screen.  Anything you edit in here will now be specific to this workspace.
5. Search for "colorTheme" and select the color theme you would like for this specific workspace.

[image]

Now, whenever you reopen that folder, the color theme will match what you set in the workspace settings.

Comment: I wish I could give you +10 for this answer.. I've been searching for a plugin with this functionality for ages, but apparently was not clever enough to just check the built-in settings. Thanks!!!

Comment: Note that it only changes when you open a new window.  It doesn't dynamically change the theme, within the same window, based on the open file.  That's what I wanted and it seems like it's not implemented by anyone yet.  The idea is here for whomever has time: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/50157#issuecomment-390933621

Comment: @Aidin There's an extension called [Theme by Language](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jsaulou.theme-by-language) that will change the theme based on the currently open file type. However, I've used this in the past and found it only worked about 95% of the time, which could get a little annoying.

Comment: This will be saved to the workspace's setting file which is version controlled. I don't want to force all the devs using this repo use my theme. Anyway I can set this setting without putting it in the repo?

Comment: I have two different windows open and when I change the settings on one window, it changes the other window's setting as well.

Comment: @Aerin Did you open the same workspace in both windows? This solution won't help with that.

Comment: @AlexMyers hi thanks for your comment! How do I open different workspaces in different windows then?

Comment: @HarryHao: Perhaps consider not having the workspace settings file be version controlled.  If that settings file has less to do with how the application actually works and has more to do with the tooling that developers use around the edges of the application, then it has less reason to be version-controlled.  Or "control" it through some other system, e.g. keep a "golden copy" somewhere that new developers start with but rarely contribute back to, so that you don't pick up developer's quirky local changes like color choice.

Comment: Awesome! This allows me to have a WSL Linux workspace with a different theme and window title prefix from my Windows workspace

Comment: Specially logged in to say thankyou to guy man. You are a savior.

Comment: I noticed that I needed to actually set up a workspace for this change to only apply to one folder. File > Save Workspace As...

Comment: I tested this in Oct 7th 2023 and noticed that when I change one workbench, all the work benches change. I remember this working in the past and I wonder if somthing has changed.

Answer (score 56):

Check out the [Window Colors](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stuart.unique-window-colors) extension which:

> Automatically adds a unique color to each window's activityBar and titleBar.

Comment: This is perfect. I want to quickly identity which project I'm working on, but don't want to change the text editor color theme. This does exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: This is the best solution! I have to have 3 projects open at the same time to run our app and it was killing me that they were all the same window colors.

Comment: To use it. ctrl-shift-p -> workspace settings -> extensions -> Window Color configurations and read what to do there.

Comment: The idea is good but the colour change is just to subtle to notice in Alt-tab etc

Answer (score 26):

Maybe  : [Peacock](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.vscode-peacock)

> Subtly change the color of your Visual Studio Code workspace. Ideal when you have multiple VS Code instances, use VS Live Share, or use VS Code's Remote features, and you want to quickly identify your editor.

And this theme combine perfect ! my 10 cents

[Tokyo Hack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ajshortt.tokyo-hack)

Comment: my doubt is if possible agroup worspace by color in same windows ???

Comment: Not sure why this mentions Tokyo Hack specifically, but the Peacock extension, written by John Papa (of [Angular style guide fame](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)? Yes, [yes it is](https://github.com/johnpapa/vscode-peacock)), is pretty straightforward. `F1`, type `Peacock: change to a favorite color`, choose a scheme from the dropdown, and profit.

Answer (score 6):

- Press ctrl + , from the keyboard.
- This will take you to the settings tab.
- Click on the **Workspace** Tab
- Type **Theme** in the search field.
- Your will see - Workbench: Color Theme
- Select the theme you want.
  And that's all

**or**

- make a **folder** in your project with **.vscode**
- make a file with the name of **settings.json** inside the folder.
- simply copy paste or write the following code. **with the theme name**

  {
  "workbench.colorTheme": "GitHub Dark"
  }

Answer (score 3):

In root folder, you can create a folder .vscode, then create a settings.json file.

Insert the follow setting in your settings.json file.

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+"
}
```

Then you can set different theme according your project.

Answer (score 3):

@Alex Myers just highlighting make sure to **choose** `Workspace`

Your answer took me straight to the right place. I made the same mistake others are complaining about, i.e. theme changes across all windows. We just missed a small but important step.

[image]